# QueryDslPredicateExecutor throwing exception on runtime

Tags: java, spring, maven, querydsl

I have this repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;

public interface IFarmRepository extends JpaRepository<Farm, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Farm>{
}
```

I have read when I extend a repository from `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`, I can expect maven to generate the `QFarm` class. This class can be used to generate `Predicate`s to pass to a newly aquired `findAll(Predicate predicate)`.

`QFarm` is being generated, but I am not even using it because I can't even get past an exception at runtime, of the inhability to create a bean, caused by:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.types.Predicate`

I am already including in my **domain project's** `pom.xml`, which is not the same as the project that throws the exception (without this, `QFarm` isn't generated):

```
    //more dependencies...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
             <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, appending those dependencies in the `<dependencies>` section of the **repositories project** has no effect whatsoever.

I think this should not be happening mostly because I am using the `com.querydsl` package, not de `com.mysema.query`. What's wrong with my setup?